# I want to get data from two tables.my query is giving data but WHERE clouse is not giving me data which i want

Tags: android

i have two tables DISCIPLINE and SUBJECT.

DISCIPLINE table has _DISCIPLINE_ID as a primary key and a DISCIPLINE_Name column.

SUBJECT table has _SUBJECT_ID as a primary key SUBJECT_Name and DISCIPLINE as a Forign key.
i want to select Subject from SUBJECT table Who has the same _DISCIPLINE_ID in the DISCIPLINE table.

here is my query:

```
SELECT DISCIPLINE._DISCIPLINE_ID,
       SUBJECT.SUBJECT_Name 
FROM DISCIPLINE,
     SUBJECT 
WHERE SUBJECT.DISCIPLINE = DISCIPLINE._DISCIPLINE_ID
```

it gives me data but it selects all the Subjects and DISCIPLINE.

Comment: Guess I am a bit confused, do you want to select a row from discipline table and then the related subjects based on that discipline?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is how your from clause is built, have you tried inner join instead of a comma seperating the table selections?